# How to prevent ReadOnly computed column in vb.net dataset to raise RowChanged event

Tags: vb.net, dataset, calculated-columns

How to prevent or detect in the code if a Read Only computed column was the cause of the RowChanged event.

```
Dim dsCambios As DataSet = DS.GetChanges()
If dsCambios.CxP_OCE_Detalle.Count > 0 Then
     ' I need this code to be executed only and always only if a non computed column was changed.
End If
```

Thanks

Comment: Since you probably know which columns are computed and which are not then you can create an Enum of Computed column names to check against.

If not [Enum].IsDefined(GetType(MyEnumOfComputedColumnNames), Somereadonlycolumn.name)  then

Comment: Please verify that this code is in a DataTable RowChanged event handler.  As far as I know, Computed columns do not cause this event to be raised; the event is raised when a row is added or changed, but not deleted (deletion raises the RowDeleted event). Even using an aggregate function such as Count(FieldName) that computes the number of rows in the table does not raise the RowChanged event when rows are deleted. I have also never seen a computed column raise the ColumnChanged event, so I'm having difficulty understanding your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the rowChanged event is raised when a computed column is changed for example a total column when I change the detail table. I made this work around:

```
    Dim dsCambios As DataSet = DS.GetChanges()
    If dsCambios.CxP_OCE_Detalle.Count > 0 Then
         Dim Modificada As Boolean = False
         Dim row As DataSet.CxP_OCE_DetalleRow
         Dim col As System.Data.DataColumn
         For Each row In dsCambios.CxP_OCE_Detalle
             For Each col In DS.CxP_OCE_Detalle.Columns
                 If Not col.ReadOnly AndAlso Not row(col.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Original).Equals(row(col.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Current)) Then Modificada = True
             Next
         Next
         If Modificada Then
              ' I need this code to be executed only and always only if a non computed column was changed.
         End If
    End If
```